# Alternate row color,mouseover,mouseout and onclick events are not working all together

Tags: jquery

Qquery code O'm using to highlight alternate row color,on `mouse-over` and `mouse-out` I'm adding a css class and `on-click` also I'm trying to add a css class but it's not reflecting.

Main issue is here at a time only two events will work together not all

```
  function rowHighlight(){  
    $(function(){
    $("#facCodes tr:odd").addClass('oddRow');
    $("#facCodes tr:even").addClass('evenEven');
    $('#facCodes tr').hover(function() {
          $(this).addClass('hover');
       },
       function() {
          $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

});
 $('#facCodes tr').click(function(event){
    $(this).addClass("click").siblings().removeClass("click");
 });

}
```

CSS codes i'm using

```
.oddRow{background:#E3E5E6;color:black}
.evenRow{background:white;color:black}
.hover{background:blue;color: white;}
.click{background:#FF9900;color: white;}
```

Comment: Can you show your CSS? Possible that oddRow & evenRow always win from hover and click CSS?

Comment: This doesn't seem to need an answer, here's an example fiddle with no changed code: http://jsfiddle.net/YY5Ld/

Comment: thanks for your answer but i was trying in IE lower version that's why its not reflecting as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/QUQzM/2/

jquery

```
$(function(){


    $('#facCode').find('tr').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('green');
    })

    $('#facCode tr:odd').addClass('blue');
    $('#facCode tr:even').addClass('yellow');


})
```

css

```
  tr:hover{
    background:grey;
}
.green, tr:active{
    background:lightgreen !important;
}
.blue{
    background:lightblue;
}
.yellow{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i have to build this code for IE so this css code won't work on IE lower version

Comment: it's now pure jquery except the hover effect. see updated fiddle